# CSS Transform Not Working in Media Query

Tags: css, media-queries, transform, translate

Using CSS Transform, but when trying to customize in media query, it no longer transforms. Just renders at finished position with no animation.

```
.hovereffect h2 {
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
font-size: 17px;
top:9rem;
padding: 10px;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
-webkit-transform: translateY(125px);
-ms-transform: translateY(125px);
transform: translateY(125px);
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)
{
.hovereffect h2 {
top:1rem !important;
-webkit-transform: translateY(50px) !important;
-ms-transform: translateY(50px) !important;
transform: translateY(50px) !important;
}

}
```

All other media queries working as expected.

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle for demo?

Comment: Do you definitely only want this to affect devices less than 480px, or could you remove the second part of your query?